# How to deploy SSIS project along with Environment variables in one step

Tags: deployment, ssis, package, project

I want to deploy my SSIS project using sql server on UAT , PROD server

I am already having project successfully implemented in DEV server.
I know we can deploy project using :

step 1 : export project from DEV server(integration service catalog-> SSISDB-> project_Name-> Projects

step 2: deploy on UAT server

step 3 : run scripts for creating environment setting

step 4 : run scripts to assign them to Environment variables

I am expecting something using which i will be able to export both project and its environments  from DEV server and then import both on UAT server in 1 step.

any suggestions will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a UAT version of your package in visual studio and build it which will create an .ispac file with UAT values for all your variables.

Then in one step you can deploy the .ispac file to your UAT server, creating the project, packages and environment variables all at once.